# Combine two stream-queries in flutter

Tags: flutter, stream, flutter-streambuilder

I want to create a streambuilder to download multiple user-profiles from firebase. But to know which users are needed I have to get the user-ids at first, these are stored in an array. So I created a method to download the array and after this is done the streambuilder loads the user-data for each user-id from the array. Here's the code:

Method to get the array (executed in initState()):

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream() async* {
job = Job.fromJson(await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection("jobs")
    .doc(widget.jobId)
    .get());
applicants = job.applicants;
await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .where('uid', whereIn: applicants)
    .snapshots();
}
```

And the streambuilder in the scaffolds' body:

```
body: isLoading
      ? Center(child: Container(child: CircularProgressIndicator()))
      : applicants.isEmpty
          ? Center(
              child: Text("no values"),
            )
          : StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: stream(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                } else { xy }
```

So my question is if there's a possibility to combine the first method and the stream. Because at the moment the user can't get any update if an application is withdrawn while using the screen.

Comment: check https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams

Comment: thanks a lot, I have not heard about async* for streams before. Great hint!

Comment: While using async* it seems to be a problem with returning the snapshots from the function, because of the rules for async* methods. But now, the snapshot.hasData return null all the time and the data can't be displayed. Do you know a way to avoid this?

Comment: I also updated the code above.

Comment: this is because you are not calling any `yield` statements (stream is empty), like `yield* your_final_firebase_stream;` so instead of second `await` use `yield*`